# Correct way to handle errors and display message in React using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, axios

What would be the best way to handle errors and display them in a React App using Hooks, at the moment if I try to break the app by mistyping the URL it shows the error but still the data sometimes also, however if I update the state to an empty array in the catch block `setData([]);`, then it works fine, I just wanted to check and see if this is the ideal way or is there another way?

**App.js**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {

  interface DataHolder {
    userId: string;
    id: string;
    title: string;
    body: string;
  }

  const [data, setData] = React.useState<DataHolder[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState<Boolean>(false);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = React.useState<Boolean>(false)

  useEffect( () => {
    const fetchData = async (): Promise<any> => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setHasError(false);
    try {
        const result = await axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        setData(result.data);
    } catch (err) {
        setHasError(true);
        setData([]);
        console.log(err);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
  fetchData()
    return () => {
        console.log('cleaned');
    }
}, [setData]);

  return (
    <>
    {hasError && <p >Something went wrong. problem with the data feed.</p>}
    {isLoading ? (
    <p >Loading ...</p>
  ) : (
    <ul>
      {data.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id} >
          <p>{item.title}</p>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional rendering should help when you are dealing with hooks.

1. Loading
2. Error
3. Data display part

You can order like this.

```
  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading ...</p>;
  }
  if (hasError) {
    return <p>Something went wrong. problem with the data feed.</p>;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {data?.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <p>{item.title}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: So, your just returning different blocks based on conditions?

Comment: yeah conditional rendering.
priority is like `loading`, `error`, `data display`.

Comment: Thanks, so need to to do anything with the state?

Comment: no need, based on your state this render works

Comment: you can also add null check like this ->. `data?.map` updated ans also.

Answer (score 1):

You can also give a condition like this, checking the length of the data

```
return (
<>
  <ul>
    {data.length > 0 ? data.map((item) => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        <p>{item.title}</p>
      </li>
    )) : null}
  </ul>
</>
```

);